# Can I make the contents of my array all lowercase?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have this array and I'm currently researching on how to make the contents of the output lowercase.

```
foreach ($city_info['links'] as $bikes => $url) {
    echo '<span><a href="'.$url.'"> '.$bikes.'</a></span>';
}
```

Comment: You're looking for [**strtolower($url)**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strtolower.asp) and [**strtolower($bikes)**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strtolower.asp).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
echo '<span><a href="' . strtolower($url) . '"> '. strtolower($bikes) .'</a></span>';
```

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strtolower.asp

Comment: Thank you even tho my question was Marked, your comment help me with my issue, I was setting it on the href url but not on the key it self.